# Quick question about $\epsilon -\delta$ proofs

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

There is one step in $\epsilon - \delta$ proofs that I hope somebody could bring clarity to for me. Say we wanted to show $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} x^2 = 4 $. Somewhere along the proof we would have the inequality $|x-2| \cdot |x+2| < \epsilon$ emerging. We could here assume $\delta \leq 1$ and thus have $|x + 2|<5$. This then means $$|x-2|\cdot |x+2|  < |x-2| \cdot 5$$

And here is where I get a bit dubious. Normally, one takes the step to casually claim that the following must hold: $$|x-2| \cdot 5 < \epsilon$$

and from there on we find (one of) our $\delta = \epsilon / 5$.

But how can one be so certain of the claim that $|x-2| \cdot |x+2| < \epsilon$ and $|x+2| < 5$ implies $|x-2|\cdot 5 < \epsilon$? We are essentially claiming that $ab < \epsilon$ and $b < c$ implies $ab < ac < \epsilon$. But of course this cannot be true, right? For example $4\cdot 5 < 21$ and $5 < 6$ implying $4\cdot 5 < 4 \cdot 6 < 21$ is non-sensical, so what is really going on?

Comment: It's the other way round. You choose your $\delta$ such that a) $\lvert x+2\rvert < 5$ and b) $\lvert x-2\rvert\cdot 5 < \varepsilon$. **That** then implies that $\lvert x-2\rvert\cdot\lvert x+2\rvert < \varepsilon$.

Comment: You're allowed to pick $\delta>0$ for which you are guaranteed $|x-2|<\delta$, which in turn **implies** the rest.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh ok! So it is like "wishful thinking"? We would really love if it were the case that $|x-2|\cdot 5 < \epsilon$ and the only to make that happen is by making sure our $\delta$ makes it so. We "want" that inequality to be true and this imposes some requirements on what kind of $\delta$ can/must be chosen. Did I get that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way.

You know the inequality $|x-2| \cdot |x+2| < |x-2| \cdot 5$ is true. You are trying to show that the inequality $|x-2| \cdot |x+2| < \epsilon$ is true. By the transitive property of inequality, you will have successfully shown that inequality to be true **if** you are able to show that $|x-2| \cdot 5 < \epsilon$. This is equivalent to showing that $|x-2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$. So by choosing $\delta = \text{min}\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{5}\}$ you are done.

Comment: Hm ok, it is almost like we are thinking one step ahead? The inequality is very suggestive of which $\delta$ *will* be able to guarantee the inequality $|x - 2| < \epsilon / 5$, right?

Comment: @thelionkingrafiki That is pretty much how I think of it, yes. Another very helpful thing is to always separate *what you know* from *what you are trying to prove*.

Comment: For sure. Thanks, that definitely cleared it up.